# complex root finding algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complex-numbers, root-finding

I have a problem of root finding. Format of the function can be arbitrary whereas I want to solve the following one:

```
f(x)= a+exp(-x**2)(b+c*x+d*x**2)
```

where a,b,c and d are given parameters, not limited to real numbers.
 I have read about the root-finding algorithm of polynomial, but still have no idea how to solve functions like I wrote here. Besides the initial guess, how do we determine the value of next iteration based on the former one, and how to find out the conjugate pairs since complex roots are wanted ?

Comment: You should probably post this on the Math StackExchange site.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is not a polynomial, because it contains the exponential function. The Newton-Raphson method is often used for numerical root-finding. It is described at length at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method, with examples.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing this link. However, actually I want to find out the complex root of which the imaginary part is significant in physics. So do you have any suggestion on this?

Comment: Newton-Raphson will typically, only converge to real solutions if you start it off on the real line, but if you start it off with a complex number it will also find complex roots. Which root it actually converges to depends on where you start it, so you may have to try a number of different starting points. The pretty diagram beside the section "Complex functions" in the link has pixels coloured in five different colours to show which of the complex roots of x^5 = 1 = 0 it converges to from that starting point.